# TypeError: plugin.test is not a function when using jest, enzyme and react-16, typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, react-16

I'm in the process of updating my react app to `react-16`, but all my tests brake. I have upgraded `enzyme`, `jest-enzyme`, `react-dom`, installed the `enzyme-adapter` , created the `setupTest.ts` enzyme file, updated my `jestconfig.js` file but I'm still getting the error. If anyone has an idea of what might be going wrong.

No dependency warnings (pertaining react|tests) when doing `npm ls`

Here is my **jestconfig**

```
{
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "transform": {
    ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testResultsProcessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/coverageprocessor.js",
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json"
  ],
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile":"<rootDir>/config/setupTests.ts",
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules", "__tests__"],
  "testRegex": "__tests__/.*\\.test\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "collectCoverageFrom": ["src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"],

...rest of code
```

**src/setupTests.ts**

```
import 'raf/polyfill'; // <= this removes the requestAnimationFrame warning error
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was writing the question and the realised the error. Was missing the following on the `jestconfig.json`

```
"snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json/serializer" // <= this part
  ],

..rest of code
```